# Read CSV file with 3 columns into Datastream. JAVA Apache Flink

Tags: java, apache-flink, data-stream, streaming-analytics

I've been struggling for a while setting up a flink application that creates a `Datastream<Tuple3<Integer, java.sql.Time, Double>>` from a csv file. The columns in this file (columns `ID, dateTime and Result`) are all String but they should be converted to Integer, java.sql.Time and Double. The other thing I want is to create tumbling windows with data per day and average the values of the `result` column in that window. The problem is that I dont know the exact syntax for it. See my code below what I tried. The last part I have sum(2), but I want to calculate the average for the windows. I did not see in a function for this in the documentation. Do I need to write a method myself for this?

```
DataStream<Tuple3<String, java.sql.Time>> dataStream = env
                .readfile(path)
                .map()
                .keyBy(0)
                .timeWindow(Time.days(1));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use your own logic to read csv or use library like univocity_parsers. And than instead of using env.**readfile** you can use env.**fromCollection**(list).

Here is the link of library In case you want:
https://www.univocity.com/pages/univocity_parsers_tutorial#using-annotations-to-map-your-java-beans

You can give your own converter with anotaion **@Convert**(conversionClass = **YourDataTimeCoverter**.class)

For average refer following flink documentation with example:.

https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-stable/dev/stream/operators/windows.html#aggregatefunction